# (pyparsing) delimitedList does not work as expected

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I have a stringized array that I am receiving from an external system. It is stripped of quotes and separated by a comma and a space.

I'm trying to use pyparsing, but I'm only getting the first element of the array. How do I specify that a word must end in alphanumeric ?

```py
value = '[AaAa=Aaa_xx_12,Bxfm=djfn_13, ldfjk=ddd,ttt=ddfs_ddfj_99]'
LBR, RBR = map(pp.Suppress, "[]")
qs = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + pp.srange("[_=,]"))
qsList = LBR + pp.delimitedList(qs, delim=', ') + RBR
print(value)
print(qsList.parseString(value).asList())
[AaAa=Aaa_xx_12,Bxfm=djfn_13, ldfjk=ddd,ttt=ddfs_ddfj_99]
# pyparsing.exceptions.ParseException: Expected ']', found 'ldfjk'  (at char 30), (line:1, col:31)
```

BR

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the mental support :D

```py
LBR, RBR = map(pp.Suppress, "[]")
element = pp.Word(pp.alphanums) + pp.Literal('=') + pp.Word(pp.alphanums + pp.srange("[_]"))

qs = pp.Combine(element + pp.OneOrMore(pp.Optional(pp.Literal(',')) + element))
qsList = LBR + pp.delimitedList(qs, delim= ', ') + RBR
print(value)
print(qsList.parseString(value).asList())

#[AaAa=Aaa_xx_12,Bxfm=djfn_13, ldfjk=ddd,ttt=ddfs_ddfj_99]
#['AaAa=Aaa_xx_12,Bxfm=djfn_13', 'ldfjk=ddd,ttt=ddfs_ddfj_99']
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your problem using pyparsing, but is there a reason why you couldn't just do `value.split(", ")`?